# Динамическое создание и удаление маркеров на Google Maps

Tags: java, сервер, google-maps-api, jsp, google-maps

Есть java код, который постоянно получает новые значения.
Что надо сделать, чтобы их отображать на карте (приходит путь до изображения маркера и местоположение маркера)?
Изначально хотел сделать Thread внутри jsp, который и показывает страницу, но после отказался.
Как это решить? Хотя-бы идею подскажите, пожалуйста.